# Эффективные ли побитовые операции в Java?

Tags: java, производительность, битовые-операции

Если брать нативные языки на подобие "C++" или "C", то там понятен выигрыш в производительности напрямую играться с регистрами, но если брать язык, где все крутится на виртуалке JVM - не совсем понятно, в чем мы можем выиграть в производительности и выиграем ли вообще??

Как работают битовые операции под капотом JVM?
Или в джава просто реализованы побитовые операции для лучшей переносимости тех же алгоритмов например с плюсов или си?

И в каких реальных случаях в java мире нам будет интересно применять на практике битовые операции?

Comment: Если уж влезли в java, то какая разница быстрые они, медленные. Уж какие есть.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> в чем мы можем выиграть в производительности

В производительности перед операциями с аналогичными результатами без применения битовых операций. Если вы думаете, что JVM делает всё медленнее, то ведь не только битовые операции страдают, верно?

> в каких рельных случаях в java мире нам будет интересно применять на практике битовіе операции?

В тех же, что и в остальном мире

> Если брать нативные языки на подобие "с++" или "С" то там понятен выиграш в производительности напрямую игратся с регистрами, но если брать язык где все крутится на виртуалке JVM

JVM - это не интерпретатор, это машина, транслирующая java-байткод в машинный код, соответствующий спецификации. В результате битовых операций будут вызываться ровно те же инструкции процессора, что и на ассемблере. Конкретно в самой битовой операции никакой потери производительности нет, основной "замедлитель" относительно условного си - это наличие сборки мусора и присущих stop-the-world пауз.

Comment: Разве первые несколько запусков функции не будут в режиме интерпретации?

Comment: @Qwertiy такое может быть, но только пока С1 не отработает, и в этом случае нас явно не интересует производительность.

Comment: А С1 - это что?

Comment: @Qwertiy компилятор первого уровня (есть еще второго, С2). Про это мало четкой документации, но по запросам типа *java c1 full profile* или *java compilaton tiers* можно найти подробности в гугле, например, [вот ответ Паньгина по теме](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35614237/2908793).

Comment: @Alex78191 Qwertiy очевидно об этом знает и имеет неплохое понимание контекста, спрашивая про первые запуски, которые происходят до того, как JIT-компилятор успел отработать.